# Factual UIAppearance limitations for VC and swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, themes, uiappearance

I was trying to go for a Theme object allowing me to well, manage the appearance of all my UI component toolbox.

Even though I understand that UIAppearance is what Apple wants you to use, I am concerned about some details. (I was able to find information here and there, but nothing concret enough to my opinion, hope this thread would maybe help others, only facts about it please o/)

Is it possible to:

- use it against custom UIViewControllers? (yep some of my UI componenents in the toolbox are actual VC)
- "override" it depending on some "rules" like, "if the componenent is in this custom view" (having a complex view hierarchy `MainView->container->somethingElse->viewToOverride`)
- use it with SwiftUI?
- init images in custom views? (if possible, any link or exemple?)

Is it still "updated" by Apple? (again thinking about SwiftUI)

Appart from that, what are the pro and cons you could think of?

What could I only do with UIAppearance, what couldn't I do with it?

Comment: Okay. I've been doing `UIKit` since 2016 and this was the first time I came across `UIAppearance`. After checking out something from 2013 (https://nshipster.com/uiappearance/) it seems I've been using it in my `AppDelegate` or `SceneDelegate` - but only for navigation bars, using the `UINavigationBar.appearance()` way of theming. My take? It has more cons than pros beyond navigation controllers. Your question really should contain something more concrete in term of links, details, or code. If you want "only facts" anyways. Maybe my link from 2013 helps.

Comment: Thanks for that link, there are some clear questions I asked, but basically I would go for the same way of implementing a theme than what's in this [Youtube UIAppearance theme video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4gWn_vKGqE)